# Where to use strip_tags() and htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php, xss

Is there a difference where I place my `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars` tag's? I read that Example 2 is better than Example 1.

But I don't understand how that can be the case, aren't these the same thing? I don't know if it also makes a difference that I am setting it back into a `$_POST[]` variable.

In my case, it's much easier to use Example 1, because no matter where I use `$_POST['test']`, I know it's safe... while I need to find ever instance that I `echo $_POST['test']` and put the tags around it for Example 2.

Is one truly version safer against XSS Leaks?

**Example 1:**

```
<?php
    $_POST['test'] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['test']));

    // other code
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?=$_POST['test']?>" />
    </form>
?>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<?php
    // other code
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['test']))?>" />
    </form>
?>
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` should be sufficient. In any case, I would *not* write it like example #1, because it's not easy "see" that the value is being encoded correctly - apply the encoding *at* the usage site. Also, updating $_POST..? I wouldn't recommend #2 either, because $_POST directly in output looks .. wrong.

Comment: example 1 is safer to use for the reason you say, you only need to use those sanitization functions once, and there's no way you could echo that without sanitization. But on the other hand, if you where to insert it to the database, you'll end up with escaped code in the database. And what if you want to use print value in a PDF? In that case you'll need to un-escape the data and it's a bad approach too.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Ahh okay, I see the cons to using Example 1... I use prepare statements anyways, and I only want to submit it back into a form.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for letting me know... I was just trying to be extra cations... So I don't need `strip_tags()` anymore, if my only use is to input it into a `<input value="" />`?

Comment: @Arian if $_POST['test'] is "<script src=hacks>" for instance, `htmlspecialchars` will emit "&lt;script src=hacks&gt;". This isn't to say that a malicious value couldn't be injected, but that a *direct* XSS script element can't be injected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both examples are equal (in output).
The problem I can see is that example #1 overwrites the `$_POST` data.
  I would advise against doing so because you cannot restore the original data at a later point in the script (e.g. if you wish to save the data into a database or output it in a non-HTML context).

---

I somehow misunderstood the question, but this part of my old answer is still applicable.

They are two different functions.

In your case you should only use `htmlspecialchars()` since this function is meant to *escape* special HTML characters (`<, >, "`).

`strip_tags()` on the contrary *strips HTML tags* (and some other stuff, [see the docs](http://php.net/strip_tags)). Do you really want this behavior? I doubt that. Stripping HTML tags differs from escaping them insofar that it really removes the tags. Escaping only "escapes" them so that the browser renders them as normal text.

Comment: But which example is better? Is there a security leak, by doing example 1?

Comment: this does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

This part of code prevent XSS perfectly.

```
<?php
    $myVar = htmlspecialchars($_POST['test']);

    // other code
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php echo $myVar; ?>" />
    </form>
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this

```
$this->message = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->message));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use $_POST['test'] in multiple spots I would use example 1 since you wont have to process the other functions (strip_tags, htmlspecialchars) over again sanitizing the same data you already have.

Comment: My first step would be to remove the "multiple spots". Then encode *all* variables used in output, as many times as they appear.